# using awk to edit a file based on a second file

Tags: awk, string

Hi I have a file with a set of number I want to edit a line whenever those numbers show up in the first column of the second file.

a.inp

```
; atom  type      fx      fy      fz
     1     1  1000  1000  1000
     5     1  1000  1000  1000
     7     1  1000  1000  1000
    11     1  1000  1000  1000
    12     1  1000  1000  1000
    13     1  1000  1000  1000
    15     1  1000  1000  1000
    17     1  1000  1000  1000
    20     1  1000  1000  1000
...
```

b.inp

```
    5
   15
   29
   48
   72
   87
...
```

output

```
; atom  type      fx      fy      fz
     1     1  1000  1000  1000
     5     1  100000  100000  100000
     7     1  1000  1000  1000
    11     1  1000  1000  1000
    12     1  1000  1000  1000
    13     1  1000  1000  1000
    15     1  100000  100000  100000
    17     1  1000  1000  1000
    20     1  1000  1000  1000
...
```

my code doesn't work for some reason?

```
awk 'NR == FNR { lines[$1]; next } 
$1 in lines { for (col = 3; col <= NF; ++col) $col *= 100 } 1' b.inp a.inp > new.inp
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how this fails. Telling us simply "it doesn't work", that isn't very helpful. I tried on my machine and it seemed to work fine. What output do you get? How is it wrong? Do you get any output? Any error messages? Also, what operating system are you using? Or, moe importantly, which implementation of awk?

Comment: It just outputs the input. doesn't match to do the modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only reproduce what you are seeing if I convert `b.inp` to a DOS text file.

If you have edited the files with a Windows text editor or produced them on a Windows system, then they may well both be DOS text files.

Convert them to Unix text files with the `dos2unix` utility.

If `b.inp` is a DOS text file, the `awk` code would include the carriage return at the end of the lines in the value of `$1` in the first block.  These carriage returns would later cause `$1 in lines` (where `$1` comes from `a.inp`) to never be true.

Converting the files to Unix text files, your code produces

```
; atom  type      fx      fy      fz
     1     1  1000  1000  1000
5 1 100000 100000 100000
     7     1  1000  1000  1000
    11     1  1000  1000  1000
    12     1  1000  1000  1000
    13     1  1000  1000  1000
15 1 100000 100000 100000
    17     1  1000  1000  1000
    20     1  1000  1000  1000
```

Comment: how can I add a tab to match the spacing?

Comment: @SarahAria Is the original file using tabs between all columns?

Comment: yes, I just want to add a tab before the rows i edit.
that should be enough.

Comment: @SarahAria You may do that with `$0 = "\t" $0` at the very end of the second block (with a `;` in-between `$col *= 100` and that).